# Touchpad won't honor natural scrolling, mouse will

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, scrolling, xinput

$ xinput list-props 15

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (137):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
libinput Tapping Enabled (275): 1
libinput Tapping Enabled Default (276): 0
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (277):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (278):    1
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (279):   0
libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (280):   0
libinput Accel Speed (281): 0.000000
libinput Accel Speed Default (282): 0.000000
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (283):   1
libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (284):   0
libinput Send Events Modes Available (255): 1, 1
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (256):    0, 0
libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (257):    0, 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled (285): 0
libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (286): 0
libinput Scroll Methods Available (287):    1, 1, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled (288):   1, 0, 0
libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (289):   1, 0, 0
libinput Click Methods Available (290): 1, 1
libinput Click Method Enabled (291):    1, 0
libinput Click Method Enabled Default (292):    1, 0
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (293):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (294):    1
Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event6"
Device Product ID (259):    2, 7
libinput Drag Lock Buttons (295):   <no items>
libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (260):    1
```

Now, if I set the trackpad's Natural Scrolling to 1 or 0, it doesn't respect it. Unnatural scrolling regardless. If I set Natural scrolling to 1 for my mouse, it respects the setting, and reverses the scrolling each time I toggle 1 or 0.

I'd really like to find the simplest, most proper solution. Previously I  was using xmodmap, but it only applies to some applications, so it was frustrating to sometimes be natural, sometimes reverse scrolling, depending on whether the app's GTK3/QT/GTK.

I'm a noob, so teaching me how to make the settings permanent or "sticky" after reboot would really help me, and every other noob with similar troubles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this "sticky" or permanent after reboots, I made the following "naturalscrolling.sh" to run as a startup item:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-prop 12 "Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
xinput set-prop 15 "Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
xinput set-prop 17 "Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
xinput set-prop 18 "Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
xinput set-prop 16 "Natural Scrolling Enabled" 1
```

Also double-click it to run after plugging in a mouse.

You'll have to choose the appropriate numbers for your system, mine usually has mice and trackpads that correspond to #12, 15, 17, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1132063).

Here is more proper workaround than OP's, until the bug is fixed:

1. Find out your device's name by running `xinput`
2. Create a file named `90-fix-for-LP1132063.conf` within `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` with this content (for enabling Natural Scrolling):

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
     Identifier "Enable Natural Scroll and Tap To Click"
     MatchDriver "libinput"
     MatchProduct "<(part of) device name>"
     Option "NaturalScrolling" "yes"
   EndSection
   ```

I suggest setting this option, too:

```
  Option "Tapping" "yes"
```

It will enable simulating the left click via tapping the touchpad.

More `libinput` options are documented here:
https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput

You can subscribe to the bug and (re)move the file once the bug is fixed.

Further reading:
https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/faq.html