# My tap to click in touchpad is not working and my synaptics touchpad changed to libinput

Tags: dual-boot, gnome, touchpad, synaptic

This is the information shown in my terminal.

[image]

Actually I installed gnome in my Ubuntu and then deleted and reinstalled it. From then my booting is slow and I have no touchpad click!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/835921/123844), and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/850629/123844) ("Tapping" option part) could help you.